# Dot word pattern matching

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a regular expression to match a word that begins with a period.  The word(s) can exist N times in a string.  I want to ensure that the word comes up whether it's at the beginning of a line, the end of a line or somewhere in the middle.  The latter part is what I'm having difficulty with.

Here is where I am at so far.

```
const string pattern = @"(^|(.* ))(?<slickText>\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)( .*|$)";

public static MatchCollection Find(string input)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(input);
    return collection;
}
```

My test pattern finds `.lee` and `.good`.  My test pattern fails to find `.bruce`:

```
static void Main()
{
    MatchCollection results = ClassName.Find("a short stump .bruce\r\nand .lee a small tree\r\n.good roots");

    foreach (Match item in results)
    {
        GroupCollection groups = item.Groups;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ", groups["slickText"].Value);

    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(results.Count > 0);
}
```

Comment: Why use the start and end of line anchors at all?

Comment: @Oded Because the regex isn't the same without them?

Comment: @Rawling - If the OP needs to match _anywhere_ in the passed in string, using the start and end of line anchors just gets in the way, no?

Comment: @Oded The newline character gives me a good terminating sequence.  Without it some sequences would otherwise be difficult to match without breaking other patterns.  E.G. How can I locate the keywords in this phrase without Multiline mode? `.one\r\n.two`

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding why the anchors are necessary. You can match .one and .two without multiline. Multiline mode simply changes the definition of `^` and `$`. A regex will still search the entire string, newlines or not. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're just looking for `\.\w+`?

**Test:**

```
var s = "a short stump .bruce\r\nand .lee a small tree\r\n.good roots";
Regex.Matches(s, @"\.\w+").Dump();
```

**Result:**

[image]

Note:

If you don't want to find `foo` in `some.foo` (because there's no whitespace between `some` and `.foo`), you can use `(?<=\W|^)\.\w+` instead.

Comment: Replacing `[0a-zA-Z0-9]` with `\w` just allows underscores (which presumably OP doesn't want) and doesn't help with the start/end of line problem at all. Replacing `(^|.* )` with `(?<=\W|^)` changes the rule for preceeding characters (any non-word character rather than anything followed by a space) again without fixing the fact that `^` and `$` don't do what OP is expecting.

Comment: @Rawling `\.\w+` will happily *match a(ll) word(s) that begins with a period*, no matter if *it's at the beginning of a line, the end of a line or somewhere in the middle*. Maybe you would like `(?<=[\n|\r| ]|^)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+` better, but IMHO there's no need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: It will match them anywhere, but it will also match them in situations where OP's regular expression explicitly won't match them (e.g. preceeded by a comma) and I choose to believe that OP explicitly _wanted_ to exclude those situations rather than writing an overcomplicated expression.

Comment: Well, the OP never mentioned that he/she don't want to match words when they are comma-separated. But as I already mentioned, the look-ahead `(?<=[\n|\r| ]|^)` will get around that, if he/she really want to, which I don't believe.

Comment: I just don't see why, when the problem is simple (OP is using `^`,`$` and `Multiline` to match `\r\n` when it only matches `\n`) everyone is suggesting rewriting the expression completely, with things which give subtly diffferent results. (Even that lookahead will give different results from the original expression if the newline issue is fixed.)

Comment: @DominicKexel - You strike me as being highly skilled with RegEx.  Do you have any recommendations for tools to assist with RegEx building or troubleshooting?

Comment: @Rawling The other way round: I don't see why, when the problem is simple (OP wants to match all words that begins with a period), anyone would suggest using `^`, `$` and `Multiline`. :-)

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey There are a lot of online regex tools (just google them), but I generally just prototype such stuff with [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: Unfortunetly, this does not work.  Cases such as `blah.me` should not match.  Maybe that was @Rawling 's concern.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Have you read the part of my answer that begins with *If you don't want to find `foo` in `some.foo`*? :-)

Comment: @DominicKexel - Why does `[\n|\r| |^]` fail?  Your version works well, `[\n|\r| ]|^`...looking to understand the difference.

Comment: When `^` is inside a bracket expression, it does no longer mean *starting position*, but *match everything not contained within the brackets*: `[ab]` => match a single character (`a` or `b`); ´[^ab]´ => match a single character (*not* `a` and *not* `b`).

Answer (score 1):

Bizarrely enough, it seems that with `RegexOptions.Multiline`, `^` and `$` will only additionally match `\n`, not `\r\n`.

Thus you get `.good` because it is preceded by `\n` which is matched by `^`, but you *don't* get `.bruce` because it is succeeded by `\r` which is not matched by `$`.

You could do a `.Replace("\r", "")` on the input, or rewrite your expression to take individual lines of input.

Edit: Or replace `$` with `\r?$` in your pattern to explicitly include the `\r`; thanks to [`SvenS`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887962/svens) for the suggestion.

Comment: Or you can accept \r explicitly like this: ( .*|\r?$) But frankly, I like Dominic's answer better, provided you don't have a reason for your rather complicated regex ;)

Comment: I like `\r?$`, it avoids having to modify or split the string before running the regex.

Comment: The behavior of `$` you mentioned is pretty clearly documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx#End (Microsoft recommends your solution: `\r?$`)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Thanks, that's the reference I was after. Good to know Sven was spot on too :)

Answer (score 0):

In your RegEx, a word has to be terminated by a space, but bruce is terminated by \r instead.

Comment: How so?  I have `( .*|$)` which I interpret as terminated by a space and 0 or more characters OR the end of the line.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right, I didn't read that thoroughly enough. But it seems at least that here is the problem somewhere (probably Rawling has hit the spot here)

Answer (score -1):

I would give this regex a go:

```
(?:.*?(\.[A-Za-z]+(?:\b|.\s)).*?)+
```

And change the RegexOptions from Multiline to Singleline - in this mode dot matches all characters including newline.

Comment: I need the matchgroup.  Updated: `(?:.*?(?<slickText>\.[A-Za-z]+(?:\b|.\s)).*?)+`.  Test string: `"a short stump .bruce\nand .lee a small tree\n.good roots.  and then .another string."` should have 4 matches, I only get 3.